# Bootstrap-collapse doesn't work correctly with custom hide/show Jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Twitter's Bootstrap framework and their collapse plugin for JQuery.  I am creating a form that when clicks on Timeframe for example a ul is shown via the collapse command.  A user will then click on an option on the revealed UL such as 7 Days Ago.  This initializes the custom code to show a hidden li and toggle the original ul closed.  This has worked fine until I added this code:

```
$('filter-reset').click(function() {
    $('.7days-select:not('.filter-selection-hidden').addClass('filter-selection-hidden');
    });
```

Now the coding has broken and the ul (filter-selection-time) or filter-selection-issues is shown on page load when it should not, and now the hidden li selections never show even when clicking the appropriate a element to unhide them.

The extensive coding can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rsxavior/Gj4Dg/

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have there is broken, it should be:

```
$('.filter-reset').click(function() {
    $('.7days-select').addClass('filter-selection-hidden');
});
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the breaking problem, but now the code isn't doing what I need it to do upon clicking .filter-reset.  It doesn't add filter-selection-hidden to the element if it doesn't return as having it.  Is there some other way I should be doing this or targeting it to happen?

Comment: Just realised that the class in your `:not` bit is the same as the class that you're trying to add. You don't need it as `addClass` won't add the class if it already has it. Edited my answer.

Comment: Timm,
Thank you very much.  I have learned something new about addClass that I didn't know before.

Comment: Woops just saw another problem! You need the dot in front of the class name in the selector so that jQuery knows you're looking for a class, so `$('filter-reset')` becomes `$('.filter-reset')`. Edited answer, let me know if it works.

Comment: It works perfectly.  I caught the dot in front of the class name so no problems :)